# Google Apps Script: sendEmail from sheet using cc and/or bcc, and avoid return of EMAIL_SENT to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that sends an email out to addresses on a sheet and then returns an entry in a column in the sheet that reads EMAIL_SENT.

```
function sendEmail()
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2000)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) 
{
var row = data[i];
var name = row [0].split(",")[1];
var emailAddress = row [2]; 
var Setting = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row [2]), "CST", "MM-dd-YYYY");
var Place = row [4];
var emailSent = row[5];
if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT")
{  
var message = "message body";
var subject = "Email to Client";

MailApp.sendEmail
(emailAddress, subject, message,
{htmlBody:message, 
cc:'internalemail@internalemail.com'});

sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

}}}
```

As you can see from the script, I am also wanting to cc a copy of the email to an internal email address, but avoid the return of the EMAIL_SENT to the sheet for this internal email.

The script as written above sends two emails, but it does not seem to send the cc'd email to the internal email address, and it returns an instance of 'EMAIL_SENT' to the column in the source sheet.

Comment: Use a different method signature for `MailApp`, i.e. this one: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage As far as not writing a value to the sheet... Then remove or make the responsible lines inaccessible.

Comment: Maybe you can check the email id to which email is being sent before setting the EMAIL_SENT data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented out some of your code and made some notes. Without seeing the sheet you were working from, it's a bit challenging to figure out where the error was, but this should work.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5/*2000*/); //Confused why you were selecting 2000 columns.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //switched to i++ instead of ++i
    //var row = data[i]; This isn't needed
    var name = data[i][0]; //row [0].split(",")[1];
    var emailAddress = data[i][1]; //row [2]; 
    var Setting = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(/*row [2]*/), "CST", "MM-dd-YYYY"); //Looks like you were creating a Date from the email address (row[2])...?
    var Place = data[i][3];
    var emailSent = data[i][4];
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT" && emailAddress != "") {
      var message = "message body";
      var subject = "Email to Client";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{htmlBody:message, cc:'internalemail@internalemail.com'});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I would organize the data, but you can obviously adapt to your needs. When setting `dataRange`, I grabbed 5 columns as the data only extends to column E.
[image]

Comment: Note that while `var row = data[i]` is not required, creating the intermediate variable avoids making the engine perform repeated lookups. As the nesting level grows, this becomes more important. (there's also no difference in `++i` vs `i++` as the 3rd statement in a `for` loop specification - arguably if the compiler performs no optimization your edit makes it less efficient.

Comment: This is almost there. The remaining issue is to prevent the return to the sheet of a final  'EMAIL_SENT' for the internally cc'd email. In other words, we only want the sheet to show 'EMAIL_SENT' for the email sent to the client email address, not to 'internalemail@internalemail.com'. As it stands, the script returns an 'EMAIL_SENT' to the sheet that populates the first empty row at the 'EMAIL_SENT' column.

Comment: @jon_win I just updated the conditional to check for an empty email address. That should do it.

Comment: @jon_win To clarify, when you call `MailApp.sendEmail()`, you're only sending one email. That email gets sent to both the "To" recipients and the "CC" recipients, but it's only one email. From what I understand of your issue, you're seeing the "EMAIL_SENT" message because, when the "To" field is blank, you can still send a message just to the "CC" address (you can try this in Gmail as proof). To prevent that, only send the email if that field is not blank. "EMAIL_SENT" will only ever be returned once per email, not per recipient.